# MySQL Lead function not working. I have tried but its working as lag function. Kindly help me

Tags: mysql, database, lead

I am trying to implement the lead function functionality in select query from yesterday onwards but its not working for me.

```
SELECT inbp_ingangsdatum,
       previous
FROM   (SELECT ibp.inbp_ingangsdatum,
               @prev                      previous,
               @prev := inbp_ingangsdatum AS prev
        FROM   base ibp,
               (SELECT @prev := '') r
        ORDER  BY inbp_ingangsdatum) AS t1;
```

**Current Output**

```
val         previous
20090101    
20120401    20090101
20120402    20120401
20120403    20120402
20120404    20120403
```

**Expected Output**

```
val         previous

20090101    20120401
20120401    20120402
20120402    20120403
20120403    20120404
20120404    20120405
```

Comment: Does it work if you order by `DESC` inside the numbering sub query?

Comment: no its not working .

Comment: @NarenP in recent versions of MySQL; an explicit ordering needs to be done first in a Derived table, and then in outer subquery, session variables are utilized. Otherwise the order is not guaranteed

Comment: @Madhur I am Using MYSQL 5.6

Comment: @NarenP Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You get points for it as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a correlated sub query and pay extra attention to ties:

```
SELECT INSD_ID, inbp_ingangsdatum, (
    SELECT inbp_ingangsdatum
    FROM base AS x
    WHERE (inbp_ingangsdatum = base.inbp_ingangsdatum AND INSD_ID > base.INSD_ID)
    OR    (inbp_ingangsdatum > base.inbp_ingangsdatum)
    ORDER BY inbp_ingangsdatum
    LIMIT 1
) AS next_date
FROM base
ORDER BY inbp_ingangsdatum, INSD_ID
```

Comment: Thanks.but,i got this answer. output:
20090101 20120401
20120401 20121001
20120401 20121001
20120401 20121001
20120401 20121001
20120401 20121001

Comment: Seems like you have "ties". You need a tie breaker column such as ID/primary key. Do you have one?

Comment: Yes INSD_ID colums contains primary key

Comment: @NarenP see revised answer. You can use it _if_ you have problems getting correct results with user variables.

Answer (score 1):

`LEAD()` function fetches the "next row" value. I don't know why are you calling it as `prev`. I am using the alias `next` instead for clarity.

While using user-defined variables, we can access previous row's value in `SELECT` clause, but getting value of the next (upcoming) row is tricky. We will have to explicitly order by `inbp_ingangsdatum` in Descending order (opposite to our final sorting requirement).

Now, we will use this result-set to get the "next" row. Due to reversed order, previous value is basically the next value.

We will finally reorder the result-set in outermost query.

---

**Schema (MySQL v5.6)**

```
Create table base (inbp_ingangsdatum int);

insert into base
values 
(20090101),
(20120401),
(20120402),
(20120403),
(20120404),
(20120405);
```

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
  dt2.val, dt2.next
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    @nxt AS next, 
    @nxt := dt.inbp_ingangsdatum AS val 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      ibp.inbp_ingangsdatum
    FROM base AS ibp
    ORDER BY ibp.inbp_ingangsdatum DESC 
  ) AS dt 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @nxt := '') AS user_init_vars
) AS dt2 
ORDER BY dt2.val;
```

**Result:**

```
| val      | next     |
| -------- | -------- |
| 20090101 | 20120401 |
| 20120401 | 20120402 |
| 20120402 | 20120403 |
| 20120403 | 20120404 |
| 20120404 | 20120405 |
| 20120405 |          |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rdPgxKC7UphoHxwU5VAVeB/0)